# Bile Blight on Chronozoa

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I [Bile Blight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBile%20Blight%5d) a [Chronozoa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChronozoa%5d) which had no counters on it, thus sending it to the graveyard, triggering the second ability and creating two tokens that are copies of it, do the copies which come into play also get -3/-3 because they're copies and Bile Blight says "until end of turn"?

A friend and I were discussing this and he seemed to think that it wouldn't since the token copies which came into play wouldn't haven been there when Bile Blight resolved, But I'm almost certain they would die since the card says "until end of turn", Bile Blight doesn't specify the creature as having been in control, and the ruling that "The name of a creature token is the same as its creature types, unless the token is a copy of another creature or the effect that created the token specifically gives it a different name."

But you never know, I could be wrong. Anyone have a certain answer?

Comment: The answer can be found in that question, though not in the accepted answer. The answer for this situation is described best in the answer by ikegami.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is right, **the new copies aren't affected** by Bile Blight.
The set of affected permanents / entities is determined at the resolution of the spell.
Of course it would have been a different story if this had been an enchantment along the lines of [Engineered Plague](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=13097)

@tengfred already guided you towards an answer that has the exact ruling in his comment, but I've pasted it here for convenience as well.

> 611.2c If a continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability modifies the characteristics or changes the controller of
>   any objects, the set of objects it affects is determined when that
>   continuous effect begins. After that point, the set won’t change.
>   (Note that this works differently than a continuous effect from a
>   static ability.) A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a
>   spell or ability that doesn’t modify the characteristics or change the
>   controller of any objects modifies the rules of the game, so it can
>   affect objects that weren’t affected when that continuous effect
>   began.